# How to iterate and print data inside <pre> with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

At my spring controller I return a `List<string>` inside the `ModelAndView`.

This list has this data:

```
{ "A", "B", "C" }
```

At the HTML I want to print this data inside a `<pre>` tag, to get **exacly** this:

```
<pre>A
B
C</pre>
```

I **dont want** to create one tag for each item like this:

```
<span th:each="item : ${myList}" th:text="${item}"></span>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is confusing do you want a `<p>` or a `<pre>`? Just put the `<p>` or `<pre> outside and use a `<span th:each ... />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for or at least the best solution I can come up with is

```
<pre th:utext="${#strings.escapeXml(#strings.listJoin(namesList,'&lt;br&gt;'))}"></pre>
```

Ok, it looks very hacked but I think it is the only option:

- th:utext renders text as it is and won't convert a `<br>` to `&lt;br&gt;`
- #strings.listJoin is pretty much self-explaining: it joins the items on a given delimiter
- #strings.escapeXml does the magic trick to convert `&lt;br&gt;` to `<br>`

In the end you get `<br/>` at the end of each item. I played around with `\n` and no escapeXml but it does not work.